# Webstart App on Windows 7 JNLP File Disappears

Tags: java, windows-7, desktop, jnlp, java-web-start

We are in the process of verifying one of our web start applications on Windows 7 as that is what our enterprise is moving to.

We are seeing the strangest thing. When a user runs the application while connected to our network over VPN, the application downloads and runs properly.

However, immediately upon disconnecting from VPN, the jnlp file is removed from the Java cache and subsequent attempts to run the application via desktop shortcut fail as the jnlp file in the cache (referenced in the shortcut) is missing.

We have also seen that at times when the user reboots, the application is completely gone from the java cache, no jar files at all, as though it were never installed.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Does it have to do with the new LocalLow security stuff in Windows 7?

Thanks in advance for any help. We are at the point with this where we may abandon Web Start entirely if we can't resolve.

Comment: i had a problem with app not showing up in the cache properly. that went away after uninstalling all installed jre/jdks and then installing the latest one.